# PHP Output array data dynamically

Tags: php, html, arrays, foreach

I created an array and I want to output the data in this array dynamically. Meaning, I have a div box and in this box I want to output different data of the array in different parts of the div.

This is the array I created (I replaced the data with placeholders):

```
$array = array(
    "contact1" => array(
        "category" => "Main Category",
        "company" => "Mother Company",
        "companyName" => "Name of the Company",
        "address" => "Musterstr. 1",
        "city" => "12345 Musterstadt",
        "phoneNumber" => "0 1234 567-8",
        "fax" => "0 1234 567-890",
        "website" => "website url",
    ),
    "contact2" => array(
        "category" => "Main Category",
        "phoneNumber" => "+49 2173 970-0",
        "fax" => "+49 2173 970-123",
    ),
    "contact3" => array(
        "category" => "Subcategory",
        "phoneNumber" => "+49 2173 970-0",
    ),
)
```

And this is the div in which I want to output the data:

```
<?php foreach ($array as $contact) : ?>
   <div class="row triangle-down ml-1 ml-sm-n1 mr-1 mr-sm-n1 bg-white contact-box">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 contact-box-left">
          <div class="col-lg-7 d-p-sm-block">
             <b>Category</b><br/>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
         <div class="row pl-2 pr-3 contact-box-right">
             <div class="col-lg-7 d-p-sm-block">
                 <p>
                    <b>Company</b><br/>
                    Company Name<br/>
                    Address<br/>
                    City<br/>
                    Phone Number<br/>
                    Fax<br/>
                    <a href="#">Website</a>
                 </p>
             </div>

             <div class="col-lg-5 contact-button">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn-sm btn-button btn-contact">Kontaktformular</a>
             </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

In this div I want to put out a specific item of the array, like Category. This should be put out in the div where I wrote "Category". Since this should be a loop for all items in the array I don't just want to output category from "contact1" (the first item) for example, but from all items in the array. But I don't really understand how I can do this.

Maybe someone can help me with this?

Comment: `echo $contact['category'];`

Comment: Where is problem? Check `$contact` array.

Comment: <div class="col-lg-7 d-p-sm-block">
             <b>Category <?=$contact['category']?></b><br/>
          </div>

Comment: @Cid and $Jagdish Chaudhary thank you both! $contact["category"] works fine!

Comment: since php7.0, you can `echo $contact['category'] ?? '';` which will prevent an 'Undefined index' notice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like two users pointed out in the comments the answer is

```
echo $contact["category"];
```

Thanks to @Cid and @Jagdish Chaudhary for pointing this out!